# terraform autoscaling group destroy timeouts

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, terraform

Is there any way to change the terraform default timeouts?

For example on `terraform apply` I frequently timeout trying to destroy autoscaling groups:

```
module.foo.aws_autoscaling_group.bar (deposed #0): Still destroying... (10m0s elapsed)
Error applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

 * aws_autoscaling_group.bar (deposed #0): group still has 1 instances
```

If I re-run the terraform apply, it works.  It seems like the timeout is 10 minutes -- I'd like to double the time so that it finishes reliably.  Alternatively, is there a way to get the auto scaling groups to delete faster?

Comment: did this work for you? I get `[ERR] Error decoding timeout: Timeout Key (create) is not supported` for an auto-scaling group... Would you mind sharing how you added this to your ASG resource declaration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a timeout to a specific resource inside terraform

```
 timeouts {
    create = "60m"
    delete = "2h"
  }
```

https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but (at least for the auto scaling group in particular), I get: `[ERR] Error decoding timeout: Timeout Key (create) is not supported` ... Any hints?

Comment: How many instances are in the asg?  Can you post your terraform with the asg resource?

Comment: For autoscaling groups, the delete key is supported as the answer says, but the create one is not. For creation timeouts you have more sophisticated options -- see https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html#waiting-for-capacity

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem when i try to delete autoscaling-group with `terraform destroy`
I solve  the problem with add the follow lines on my resource creation section:

```
    timeouts {  
    delete = "60m"
  }
```